# Removing an element in a 2D array by collapsing all elements

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am making a program that keeps track of employee information. I have a 2D array containing the records ([employee][piece_of_data]), and I want to be able to delete a record by looping through the array and making the current record equal to the following one.

Right now it is deleting the record AHEAD of the one selected rather than the current and it seems that no matter how I manipulate it, it won't delete the proper record.

Here is my code:

```
//Delete current record, collapse records into it
    for (int iLoop = iEmployee; iLoop < iEmployeeCount; iLoop++){
        for (int iLoop2 = 0; iLoop2 <= 20; iLoop2++){
            sData[iLoop][iLoop2] = sData[iLoop + 1][iLoop2];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try ` sData[iLoop - 1][iLoop2] = sData[iLoop][iLoop2];`?

Comment: Yes, but no matter how i change it like this, i.e. sData[iLoop - 2][iLoop2] = sData[iLoop - 1][iLoop2];, it still removes the record following the current one, only eventually it gives an out of bounds exception. I'm so confused, this is such a simple piece of code.

Comment: Does it have to be a fixed array? Or would you be able to use an ArrayList or other Collection? Is there a reason you can't create an Object class?

Comment: Honestly, I'm a beginner and the project this code is from is the biggest and most complex I've ever done and changing something like that at this point would really mess me up. I've never used an ArrayList or other things like that before but I figure I would have to rebuild a ton of things. (I only have 2 days until I have to hand it in).

Comment: How big of a project is it? It might be easiest to use an ArrayList of Employees with an array of the data in the ArrayList. It would not be too bad to replace the matrix with this. Look at how to use ArrayLists they are extremely useful.

Comment: Try this:    
`ArrayList<String[]> a=new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(sData));`
`a.remove(iEmployee);`

Comment: Its really big (for me). Right now there's over 2000 lines but just having to replace all the references to the array would take me hours to get right and now it's due tomorrow morning. I'd guess there's probably 100-200 references to the array. I might have to show it to my teacher with the bug.

Comment: Does the matrix have to be a fixed size? This method that you are doing will duplicate an employee.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that instead of working with this weird double array you solve this problem in the correct way. The current code is messy and not maintainable. Worse, it seems like it probably duplicates records because after you left shift all the columns in your 2D array the last column will contain a duplicate of the second last column.

Java is an Object Oriented language. Use objects.

```
//declare a class to store the info about one employee
//this will replace one column in your double array
public class Employee {
 //each one of these fields corresponds to one cell in your double array
 public string data1; 
 public string data2;
 public string data3;
}
```

And then store them in a linked list:

```
//this is just an example of how you would add employees to a list instead of an array
LinkedList<Employee> employees = new LinkedList<>(); //make a linked list
Employee toAdd = new Employee();                     //make an employee
toAdd.data1 = "example";                             //set up his data
toAdd.data2 = "setting";
toAdd.data3 = "fields";
employees.add(toAdd);                                //add him to the list
```

Then to remove an employee, instead of doing this complicated and inefficent method with arrays, just get a link to the employee you want and call

```
employees.remove(iEmployee);
```

where iEmployee is the number in the list of the employee to remove.

Comment: Thanks, really helpful stuff here, I'll be sure to refer back here before I think of making something like this again. This is for my high school final performance task and I've long since passed the point of no return. If I were to my start again I would do a lot of things differently (this included) but I'm already nearing the end and everything in my program revolves around this particular array. Just a fix for this problem is what I need right now.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are unable to convert the matrix to Objects and are unable to use an ArrayList for the entire thing here is a way to do it:

```
ArrayList<String[]> a=new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(sData));
a.remove(iEmployee);
```

This will convert the matrix to an ArrayList of String arrays.

```
Object[] oa = a.toArray();
for(int i = 0; i<oa.length; i++){
    sData[i] = (String[])oa[i];
}
```

This will then convert the ArrayList back into sData matrix.

Edit: This will not work if you except to have a set matrix size somewhere else. This will resize the matrix after you remove the data.